# Selenium HTML open tags

Tags: html, xpath, selenium, xhtml

Maybe the answer is straightforward, but does anyone know for sure, whether Selenium with XPath work properly with HTML which is not XML, i. e. contains open tags? In my case those are `<col>` and `<input>`.

The reason I'm asking is that our automation testing team often encounters the problem, that in some cases Selenium XPath selector doesn't work, whereas the same XPath selects elements on the same page, when we use it in FirePath, for example. Can it be because of the fact, that our HTML is not a valid XML? As far as I know, XPath was originally invented to deal with XML data.

Comment: I'm not convinced about Selenium's XPath implementation. While Quentin's answer is correct, there may well be specific XPaths that Selenium has difficulty with. If you encounter one, it's probably best to ask a question about that particular XPath.

Comment: Are your pages valid HTML? Is it just XPath selectors that go a bit wrong? (Have you tried other selectors, if possible.)

Comment: There are some problems with validity as HTML. I can't fix all of them, because most of them are from GWT, like negative value of tabIndex or empty `<select>` section. But there are a few misused tags  we use. I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath operates on a DOM. Browsers generate a DOM. Selenium interacts with browsers.

Dealing with HTML should not cause a problem for it.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium should be fine as it runs through the dom, so html even broken html should be ok. 
What I have found usefull for automation testing is adding id's or classes for testers to use, this seems to give better and faster results.

Comment: Adding ID's is a good idea, but in our application it will take very much time, that's why for now we have to use the nasty XPath way of selecting the elements.